# Verilog code for wighted average circuit

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, weighted-average

I am trying to synthesize a weighted sum circuit which will essentially implement the following equation,

**out=out+a[i]*w[i]  ,  where i=0,1..n**

I have written the following code but synthesizing in design vision environment generates error as following

> ELAB-368 (error) %s Net '%s', or a directly connected net, is driven
>   by more than one source, and at least one source is a constant net.

```
module weighted_sum #(parameter n=10)(input [7:0] a[3:0], input [7:0] w[3:0], output [7:0] out);

assign out=0;
genvar i;
generate
for (i=0;i<n;i=i+1) begin:block1
out=out+a[i]*b[i];
end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

Any direction is appreciated.

Thanks
Farhana

Comment: What is `b`? `out` is assigned `0` and you are driving `out` in generate block also. I assume a typo for `assign` in `assign out=out+a[i]*b[i];`

Comment: sorry that was a typo. It was not in the main code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a generate loop for this. generate is for replicating hardware. You want to logic, which should use an `always` block:

```
always_comb begin // SystemVerilog use "always_comb", Verilog use "always @*"
  out = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<n;i=i+1) begin
    out += a[i]*b[i];
  end
end
```

FYI, Verilog does not support multi-dimensional arrays on the port-list (ex `input [7:0] a[3:0]`). Verilog only supports vector type ports (aka single dimension packed arrays). SystemVerilog does support multi-dimensional arrays on ports, but some tools may have limitations on support so refer to your manuals and experiment.

Also, your module header does not scale. `a` & `b` will always be 4 entries of 8bits, and `out` will likely overflow. I suggest the following module header:

```
module weighted_sum #(parameter N=10)(
  input [7:0] a[N], input [7:0] w[N], // scaling input depth
  output logic [14+N:0] out); // scaling for overflow protection
```

Comment: thanks a lot. The suggestion worked. I am working on SystemVerilog environment and my complier can handle multidimensional input array. This is a relief otherwise some extra coding would have required.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Greg's answer, the tool is barfing on two different assignments to the signal `out`.
First
`assign out=0;`
Second
`out=out+a[i]*b[i];`